# How to rounded border bottom of an element?

Tags: css, web-frontend, border-radius

I am building this main nav bar, as the active/hover state I need to get the border bottom in color.
My problem is how could I round the inner top corners?
I understand that I could create an element, add a height, width, bg color and round it with border-radius,But I'd like to know if it is possible to make this with border-bottom.

I've attached the design so you can see what I mean. Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llHiJ.png)

Comment: Please attach any (related) code you already have

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use a pseudo-element such as `::after` and give it a specific height. Then use `borer-top-left-radius` and `border-top-right-radius` to round the corners with the equal value of the height:

```js
const ANCHORS = document.querySelectorAll('menu a');

ANCHORS.forEach(anchor => 
  anchor.addEventListener('click', function(element) {
    document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
    element.target.classList.add('active');
  }) 
)
```

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 2em 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}


a:hover::after,
a.active::after {
  --block-thickness: 0.5em;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: var(--block-thickness);
  background-color: blue;
  border-top-left-radius: var(--block-thickness);
  border-top-right-radius: var(--block-thickness);
}


/* styling for the navbar */
menu {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <li><a href="#link" class="active">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link">Link 4</a></li>
</menu>
```

EDIT: To have the border only displayed on hover, you can use the `:hover` pseudo-selector before you use the `::after` pseudo-selector. The active state is only solvable through JS and requires the usage of adding and removing a class.

Comment: Thank you! it works except although I am applying to a::after it's positioning under all a's not just the hover/active one.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is using Tailwind CSS. Run below codes in the terminal of the VS CODE.

[code link that is to be run in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVuap.jpg)

This way you will get ready to use TAILWIND CSS.

REMEMBER:- Code snippet will not work until codes in provided image run in the terminal of the VS Code.

*Main code to make the bottom of an element rounded* **border-2 rounded-b-lg**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/input.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class=" bg-gray-400 h-10 ">
    <ul class="flex space-x-4 mx-4">
      <li class=" hover:border-2 rounded-b-lg border-b-green-500 border-purple-700">Home</li>
      <li class=" ">Help</li>
      <li class=" ">Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "*The easiest way*" - OP did not tag this question with `tailwind` - Installing a fully fletched CSS library for this doesn't seems to be the easiest way

Comment: Much more easier than writing a lengthy code.

Comment: Furthermore, I've tested your code and this does,'t even do what OP wants. Here is a [demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/uzNx76Upgn?layout=horizontal), I've already removed the extra (unwanted) borders, but please have a look at OP's question and desired result.

Comment: thanks for the reply. My prefer is not using bootstrap or tailwind.

Comment: Code didn't work because you didn't follow the steps that was provided in the given link. I've understood completely by now what Sayeh was looking for and I apologise for that.

Comment: "*Code didn't work because you didn't follow...*" - What are you on about? The demo I've linked is hosted on the [official sandbox](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) of tailwind.